# Use JavaScripts methods on C#

Tags: c#, javascript, methods

I'm download web page and parse javascript code, which have in code hash and java decode function... 
please I want to call javascript decode method from C# program...

In web page I've :

```
window.decoded_hashes = {};
window.decodehash = function(hash) {
  window.dec_hash(hash);
  return window.decoded_hashes[hash];
window.dec_hash = function(hash) {
  (function(__){window.decoded_hashes[hash] = _(__,8,_____(__)-12)+_(__,0,5);})((function(__){____='';for(___=0;___<_____(__);++___)____+=______(__,_____(__)-___-1);return window[_______(88,11,-13)]?__:____;})((function(__){____=window[_______(103,-2)]?'':'____';for(___=0;___<_____(__);++___)____+=(function(__){return __>111?(121-__):_______(__);})(__.charCodeAt(___));return ____;})((function(__){_______=function(){var _='',__=0,___=arguments;for(var ____=0;____<___.length;++____)_+=String.fromCharCode(__+=___[____]);return _;};______=function(__,___){return __.charAt(___);};_____=function(__){return __.length;};____=(_=function(_,__,___){____='';(___=___?___:(_____(_)-__));for(;___;--___)____+=(function(_,__){return ______(_,__)})(_,__++);return ____;})(__,3,3);____+=_(__,0,2)+_(__,8);return ____;})(hash))));
}


window.wall_post_hash = decodehash('tsucuqtyqvedvvpruuqasavdpwdcxafcystrdfvsyd');
```

And I must sent decode hash on server... hash in () - dinamic

How to make easier? I've found Rhino and IKVM, but have not understood yet...

Give me advice Pls...

Sorry for my English;)

Answer (score 0):

You could include Microsoft.JScript in your project references.

Check out an example from [Rick Strahl's](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/10688.aspx) on how you can use Eval to get your results.

Here's an implementation I managed to work out after some debugging and changes. It returns the same result as your example. One issue is that .Net don't seem to work with the function "arguments" variable. So I added 5 variables to that function to get it to work. Seems the most which is passed is 3.

```
package Pack
{
    class JSEval
    {        
        public function MyEval(inputhash : String) : String
        {
            var ___ = 0;
            var _= '';
            var ____ = '';
            var _______;
            var ______;
            var _____;


            var ____ = (_ = function(_, __, ___) {
                ____ = '';
                (___ = ___ ? ___ : (_____(_) - __));
                for (; ___; --___) ____ += (function(_, __) {
                    return ______(_, __)
                })(_, __++);
                return ____;
            })                

            var mywin = new Object();
            mywin.decoded_hashes = {};
            mywin.dec_hash = function(hash) {
            (function(__) {
                mywin.decoded_hashes[hash] = _(__, 8, _____(__) - 12) + _(__, 0, 5);
            })((function(__) {
                var ____ = '';
                for (___ = 0; ___ < _____(__); ++___) ____ += ______(__, _____(__) - ___ - 1);
                return mywin[_______(88, 11, -13)] ? __ : ____;
            })((function(input) {
                var res = mywin[_______(103, -2)] ? '' : '____';

                for (var i = 0; i < _____(input); ++i) res += (function(input) {
                    return input > 111 ? (121 - input) : _______(input);
                })(input.charCodeAt(i));                
                return res;
            })((function(__) {
                _______ = function(a,b,c,d,e) {                    
                    var arguments = new Array();
                    if( a != undefined )
                        arguments.push(a);
                    if( b != undefined )
                        arguments.push(b);
                    if( c != undefined )
                        arguments.push(c);
                    if( d != undefined )
                        arguments.push(d);
                    if( e != undefined )
                        arguments.push(e);
                    var _ = '';
                    var __ = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) _ += String.fromCharCode(__ += arguments[i]);
                    return _;
                };
                ______ = function(__, ___) {
                    return __.charAt(___);
                };
                _____ = function(__) {
                    return __.length;
                };
                ____ = (_ = function(_, __, ___) {
                    ____ = '';
                    (___ = ___ ? ___ : (_____(_) - __));
                    for (; ___; --___) ____ += (function(_, __) {
                        return ______(_, __)
                    })(_, __++);
                    return ____;
                })(__, 3, 3);

                ____ += _(__, 0, 2) + _(__, 8);
                return ____;
            })(hash))));
        }
        mywin.decodehash = function(hash) {
            mywin.dec_hash(hash);
            return mywin.decoded_hashes[hash];
        }


        return mywin.decodehash(inputhash);                
        }
    }
}
```